# RISCV Linux Syscall codes

Tags: linux, riscv

I'm writing RISCV assembly and I need to perform some syscalls. Based on other answers on this site I know I need to load the syscall code into `a7` and launch `ecall`.

How do I know what code to use?

EDIT: I'm trying to use write, read, close,wait4, fork.

I found two sources of syscall codes that are different:

https://github.com/westerndigitalcorporation/RISC-V-Linux/blob/master/linux/arch/s390/kernel/syscalls/syscall.tbl

and directly in the file generated after running `make linux` using the RISCV toolchain: sysroot/usr/include/asm-generic/unistd.h

Which should I use? (Fork is in the first but not the second)

Comment: why do you need to make direct system calls? Can't you use the C library?

Comment: `getenv` and `atoi` aren't system calls, they're ordinary user-mode functions. Why would you need to involve the kernel to parse a number?

Comment: @Barmar Ah ok for getenv and atoi I need to figure out how to use the relevant C libraries in assembly but that's a different question.

Comment: If you can't find a consistent list of system call numbers, you should use the C library for that, too. It will have the correct mappings for the current environment.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, I think I can simply use `call <syscall>` in assembly code before assembling and linking in the necessary C libraries, instead of directly setting up `a7` and using `ecall`. Will update if it works...

Comment: I'd be wary of that. I'm not familiar with the RISCV calling convention but it might not be the best idea to save and restore register state manually which you'd likely have to do if you use `ecall`/`call`.

Comment: See [RISC V Calling Convention](https://riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/riscv-calling.pdf)

Comment: I dont understand what you mean. how else do you invoke system calls without `ecall`/`call`?

Comment: Well just like how in x86 Linux you don't usually use `call` directly to issue the `read()` syscall but instead use the C wrappers around it, I'm suggesting doing the same in this case.